# jQuery override event preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm overriding the `slideDown` jQuery event so I can capture it and run my own code:

```
; (function ($) {
        var orig_slideDown = $.fn.slideDown;

        $.fn.slideDown = function () {
            $(this).trigger('slideDown');
            orig_slideDown.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

I can now bind my code to this event:

```
$('.step2').bind('slideDown', function (e) {
if(ConditionsNotMet()){
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

But I am unable to cancel it with `e.preventDefault()`.  Is there someting I need to add to support this?

Comment: how do you cancel slidedown?

Comment: by not allowing it to begin. However, since the act of sliding down isn't directly limited to the event being fired, you can't prevent it in that way.

Comment: Default actions are only associated with standard events, e.g. clicking on a submit button submits the form, keyboard events in an input field update the value. There's no default action associated with the event you created, so nothing to prevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here is to use `.triggerHandler`, and instead of using preventDefault, just return false. You can then check the return value of triggerHandler and use that to decide whether or not to start the slidedown.

```
;(function ($) {
    var orig_slideDown = $.fn.slideDown;

    $.fn.slideDown = function () {
        var orig_arguments = arguments;
        return this.each(function () {
            if ($(this).triggerHandler('slideDown') !== false) {
                orig_slideDown.apply($(this), orig_arguments);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.step2').bind('slideDown', function () {
    if(someCondition()){
        return false;
    }
});
```

(also corrected plugin such that it properly chains and runs on all selected elements)

https://jsfiddle.net/xqz2933v/